# Remove first line from Word Document process it and put a new line at the beginning of the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am developing an application wherein I need to delete the first line of several word documents, merge them, merge their tables into one and place it at the top, remove all the individual tables which are merged, and then giving the merged table a name.

I am through with almost everything except removing the first line of the individual word documents (which will be merged into one) and Putting name string to the newly generated table in the new document on top of the table. The newly generated table will be placed at the top of the new document (which is result of merging of all other documents).

Can someone suggest a way to do it. If possible, deletion of first two lines will help more.

Comment: In the past I used cheap trick to help with handling horribly formatted documents. Via Word automation I made it save files to html files, which not only normalized formatting (<tittle>, <p>, instead of random \n \t and font setting, in your case you will also get to abuse <table>) but also changed problem of parsing Word docs to parsing html files. Although performance was rather bad, it was acceptable as mere parser of documentation of several years. Another approach could be Word plugin instead of automation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing first line could mean removing first paragraph or just first line as you could see it. They are not the same therefore I provide both solution below

```
'Remark: for ActiveDocument

'removing first paragraph
ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1).Range.Delete

'removing first line
ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
Selection.MoveEnd wdLine
Selection.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks KazJaw, it worked. going ahead with the code now. Thanks again... :)